# Existence of Vector Field Commuting with Given Collection

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

Let $U$ be some open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$, and suppose $X_1,\ldots, X_K$ are a collection of smooth vector fields mapping $U \to \mathbb{R}^N$.

Is there a simple condition which characterizes when there exists, at least locally, a nowhere-zero vector field $Y$ such that the Lie brackets $[X_k, Y] = 0$, for all $k =1 ,\ldots, K$?

If such a $Y$ exists then $Y$ commutes with each $[X_j, X_k]$ but this seems to not be obviously useful. This smells like it's somehow just the Frobenius theorem but I'm not familiar enough to be able to make the connection as clear as I'd like.

Comment: I don't see how Frobenius is going to help you. Have you taken the simplest example of two non-commuting vector fields in $\Bbb R^3$ and worked out the PDEs that $Y$ must satisfy?

Comment: @TedShifrin Writing out as PDEs I just have: $J_{X_k} Y - J_Y X_k = 0$ for all $k=1,\ldots, K$, which seems (perhaps naively) like a nice enough system of PDEs. But I wouldn't expect it to always be solvable non-trivially as $K$ grows. As someone who's not terribly familiar with this space I was curious if there was some standard condition to guarantee a non-zero solution.